# MySQL query in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm attempting to use functions to get certain data from database. For example, I want to get info from an user with ID 1.

```
try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "root", "password");
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function getUser($id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ID = '$id'");
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
        echo $row['playername'];
        $user[] = $row;
    }
}
```

And then in my index.php.

```
include 'inc/db.php';

getUser("1");
foreach($user AS $user) {
    echo $user['ID'];
}
```

The first echo works, I get the username displayed, but the foreach doesn't echo anything. I tried to `var_dump($user);` but ended up getting `NULL`.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to do `foreach($var as $var)`. That is, to use the same `var` name.

Comment: I'm not that good in PHP, still studying. What would you suggest me to use to get data from an user?

Comment: You need to learn about PHP variable scope. `$user` inside your `getUser` method is COMPLETELY different from the (undefined) `$user` you're trying to use in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are writing too much code. PHP can't process so much, chokes and dies.
All you actually need is

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "root", "password");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

function getUser($id)
{
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ID = ?");
    $query->execute(array($id));
    return $query->fetch();
}

$user = getUser(1);
echo $user['playername'];
```

to make it little more serious, you should use prepared statement to pass variable into query and return data from the function.

Comment: "php can't process so much and dies"? Huh? HUH!?

Comment: This works great for getting a single item. How about if I want to get all users and use foreach method for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have:

```
function getUser(...) {
  ...
  $user = array();
  while(...) {
      $user[] = $row;
  }
  return $user;
}
```

And then in your main code:

```
$users = getUser(1);
foreach($users as $user) { .... }
```

Right now you're defining local variables and then not returning them, so they're lost when the method exits. And then not capturing any possible returned values anyways, making your code basically pointless.

Comment: I attempted to echo value with the code you provided, but I am ending up getting values such as "117744KKhhhhhhhh1111001111112211551122" which are not the values that are in the database.